# Display Addiional Fields When Selection Made For A Drop Down In C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue which I suspect will be easy but for the life of me I can not think how to do it.

I have a webpage which has 2 drop down list and an input field but I want my second drop down list to display different values upon the selection of the first drop down list.

My code in my view is:

```
AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Template template = new AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Template();
template.HtmlTemplate = ((AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Translators.SIPPAdditionalContributions)Model.Data).PageText;
template.Nvc.Add("[!SourceDropDown]", Html.DropDownList("Source_DropDownList", new String[] { "- - Please select - -", "Member", "Employer" }, null, new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "AdditionalFieldsCheck(this);" }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!SourceErrorMessage]", AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Website.CStr(Html.ValidationMessage("Source_DropDownList")));
template.Nvc.Add("[!PaymentTypeDropDown]", Html.DropDownList("PaymentType_DropDownList", new String[] { "- - Please select - -", "Cheque", "Electronic payment" }, null, new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "PaymentTypeButtonDisplay(this);" }).ToHtmlString());
```

Using the above there are placeholders in my CMS which put there fields where they are to go.

Below is screen shot of the fields:

[image]

My site is built using bootstrap 3 and HTML 5.  I don't want to add any code or java to my CMS if I can help it.

Will I need some code in my helper to help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I already had some logic in my code to show and hide items so I used the `ShowLayer` and `HideLayer`